# Add text on a new line in a UILabel

Tags: swift

I am trying to add text to a new line of a `UILabel`, now it replaces the current text.

- How do you append text to a `UILabel`?
- How do you add a new line to a `UILabel`?

---

```
@IBAction func sign(sender: AnyObject) {


    if (ForUs.text == ""){
        input1 = 0

    } else{

        input1 = Int((ForUs.text)!)!
    }

    if (ForThem.text == ""){

        input2 = 0
    } else {
        input2 = Int((ForThem.text)!)!
    }

    ForUs.text?.removeAll()
    ForThem.text?.removeAll()

    input1total += input1
    input2total += input2

    Us.text = "\(input1total)"
    Them.text = "\(input2total)"


    if ( input1total >= 152){
        print("you win")

    }
    if (input2total >= 152){
        print("you lose")
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a lot of issues with the code you posted.

First of all, make the code clear. We should be able to copy the code, paste it in, for example a playground, and it should work. Sometimes this is not possible but in your case it is.

Issues with your code:

- unwrap your optionals, every time you don't a unicorn dies!!
- you can't convert from a Swift `String` to an `Int` directly

This method converts a `String` to an `Int` in way that doesn't result in an optional value.

```
// elaborate for extra clarity
let forUsTextNSString = forUsText as NSString
let forUSTextFloat = forUsTextNSString.floatValue
input1 = Int(forUSTextFloat)
```

This is the updated code, it now compiles:

```
// stuff I used to test this
var forUs = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100))
var forThem = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100))

var us = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100))
var them = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100))

// more stuff I used to test this
var input1 : Int = 0
var input2 : Int = 0
var input1total : Int = 0
var input2total : Int = 0

func sign() { // changed to non IB method, don't copy and paste this

    // unwrap some optionals (google nil coalescing operator)
    let forUsText = forUs.text ?? ""
    let forThemText = forThem.text ?? ""
    var usText = us.text ?? ""
    var themText = them.text ?? ""

    // elaborate way to convert String to Int (empty string returns a 0)
    let forUsTextNSString = forUsText as NSString
    let forUSTextFloat = forUsTextNSString.floatValue
    input1 = Int(forUSTextFloat)

    // compact method
    input1 = Int((forUsText as NSString).floatValue)
    input2 = Int((forThemText as NSString).floatValue)

    forUs.text = ""
    forThem.text = ""

    input1total += input1
    input2total += input2

    us.text = "\(input1total)"
    them.text = "\(input2total)"


    if ( input1total >= 152){
        print("you win")

    }
    if (input2total >= 152){
        print("you lose")
    }    
}
```

---

Now to answer the question:

- `UILabel` has an attribute `numberOfLines`
- `\n` is used to insert a line break in text

Increase `numberOfLines` and add the new text with `\n` before the new text.

```
usText += "\n\(input1total)"
themText += "\n\(input2total)"

// change += 1 to = 2 if that is what you actually need
us.numberOfLines += 1
them.numberOfLines += 1

us.text = usText
them.text = themText
```

Comment: @MohammedAlsaiari no problem, don't forget to upvote if you like the answer.